# Update database with checkbox php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I want to update the database with a checkbox in checked state.

- If it is checked then update the database with 1.
- Else if it is unchecked then update it with 0.

It works fine but it doesn't work if unchecked.

```
<?php 
include('lib/db.php');

$facebook_id ="10001088";
$query1 = "SELECT `video`,`quran`,`medical`,`groups`  FROM `man_facebook`.`users` WHERE `facebook_id`='$facebook_id'";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $video = $result['video'];
    $quran = $result['quran'];
    $medical = $result['medical'];
    $groups = $result['groups'];
    echo $video;
 //   echo $quran;
?>

<form method="post"  action="<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" >

<input type="checkbox" name="video" id="video" value="<?echo $video;?>" <?php
if($video == '1'){
     echo "checked='checked'";
}
 else {}
echo "/>"
?> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
}
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if (is_numeric($_POST['video']) && $_POST['video'] <2 )
{
 $video1 = isset($_POST['video']) ? '1' : '0';


 echo $video1;
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `man_facebook`.`users` 
SET `video` ='$video1'
WHERE `facebook_id`='$facebook_id'");

$video = $video1;
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" />';

    }
    }
//echo $query;
 //header("Location: updatesql.php"); 

?>
```

Can I also use jquery to update it smoothly?

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. This is an interface from the 1990s that's in the process of being retired. You should be using `mysqli` and PDO to benefit from reliable, proper [SQL injection protection](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: U can and definitely should jquery to update the checkbox!

Comment: okay i will use mysqli 
but i want to solve that problem first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this part a bit weird:

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['video']) && $_POST['video'] <2 )
{
    $video1 = isset($_POST['video']) ? '1' : '0';
```

You first check if it is numeric and then check if it is set. If it wasn't set, that if would become false automatically. In other words, `$video` is always 1. Assuming `$video` can be only true/false (or maybe it comes as "checked"/"unchecked", not really sure), use it like this:

```
$video1 = ($video ? '1' : '0');
```

Hopefully I spotted the issue successfully :)

**UPDATE**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="video" id="video" value="video" <?php
if($video == '1'){
     echo "checked='checked'";
}
echo "/>";

...

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['video']; // again, please tell what it outputs here!!!
    $video1 = (($_POST['video'] == "video") ? '1' : '0');
```

Comment: No no, I mean you are checking it in some wrong way. Just echo `$_POST['video']` in both cases(checked and unchecked) and tell me what you get :P

Comment: Maybe it is because you also define it's value? Try getting rid of this part: ` value="<?echo $video;?>" `

Comment: Updated, please tell what it ouputs in both cases :)

Comment: output is "video" ...but it is worked :) thanks ..... can u help me to  use jquery instead ?

Comment: I am afraid I not very good at it :( You should try putting another question and someone will help you for sure :) Glad I helped on that issue :)

Answer (score -1):

checkbox update

```
if (isset($_POST["send"]) && $_POST["send"] == "ok") {

    foreach ($_POST['membre'] as $id => $data) {

        mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET param1='" . $data['param'] . "'  WHERE id='" . $id . "'");
    }
}

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok" />
    <td class="cel2" style=" width: 100px;">
        <input name="membre[<?php print $val['id']; ?>][param]" type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 7px; width: 30px;" value="1" id="param" <?php if ($val['p'] == '1') print 'checked'; ?> />
    </td>
</form>
```